# issue in rewriting strlen from C to Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, strlen

please could you help me? I have to rewrite strlen function from C to Assembly language. Iput string is ended with "0h". Output length is without char "0". Input is alway ended with "0h"
I have something like that but it doesnt work:

```
[segment .data use32] 

; ******************************************************************

str:          resb 50
str1:         resb 50
str2:         resb 50
aTmpWord:     dw 0   
aTmpDWord:    dd 0  
strlen:
push EBP
mov EBP, ESP
mov AL, 0h
mov EDI, dword [EBP + 8]
mov EBX, 0

vypocet_str:
cld
repne scasb
je koniec_str
inc EBX
mov EDI, [EDI + EBX]
jmp vypocet_str

koniec_str:
mov EAX, EBX
mov ESP, EBP 
pop EBP
ret
;************
prologue
push dword [str]
call strlen
call WriteNewLine
call WriteInt32
epilogue
```

Comment: It would help if you named which architecture you are targeting with this.

Comment: Please be more precise than "it doesn't work": what should it do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: Also - what are you calling with - you start by pushing a register, and then copying another in I think - what is in the ESP register? Comments are allowed in assembler, and they should be meaningful like any other system.

Comment: What's the point of the `vypocet_str` loop when you're prefixing `scasb` with `repne` ?

Comment: Consult the instruction set reference on how to use `repne scasb`. Hint: you need to set up `ecx` and you don't need the additional loop with `ebx`.

Comment: Btw, `mov EDI, [EDI + EBX]` is a memory access. If you meant to set `EDI` to `EDI + EBX` you should've used `lea edi,[edi+ebx]` or `add edi,ebx`. (that line of code shouldn't be necessary at all for your function though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several mistakes in your code

1) `strlen` is officially declared as `size_t strlen(const char *s);`. Argument is a pointer to a string. With `push dword [str]` you don't pass a pointer, but the first 4 bytes of the string. Change it to `push str`. NASM (unlike MASM) calculates then the address of `str`.

2) The `cdecl` calling conventions determines that arguments are passed on the stack and the caller must clear the stack. You correctly pushed the argument but don't clear the stack. Add a `add esp, 4` after `call strlen`.

3) `repne` needs an initialization of `ECX`. This is the maximal count of the repetitions.

4) `repne` is the instruction for a loop. You don't need an extra loop (`jmp vypocet_str`). It repeats the following instruction while ECX>0 and the instruction don't tell an "equal" (zero flag set). So ECX can be used to determine the counts of the repne-run - with a little adjust.

TL;DR: here is your homework in a beautiful form:

```
%include 'rw32.inc'     ; http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~iklubal/IAS/

[segment .data use32]

    str: db "hello world", 0

[segment .code use32]

    strlen:
        push ebp
        mov ebp, esp
        mov al, 0
        mov edi, dword [EBP + 8]
        mov ecx, -1
        repne scasb
        neg ecx
        sub ecx, 2
        mov eax, ecx
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret

    prologue
    push str
    call strlen
    add esp, 4
    call WriteNewLine
    call WriteInt32
    epilogue
```